# What's the most efficient way of making hamcrest assertions for a JSON object with many keys?

Tags: json, rest-assured, matcher, hamcrest

I am making assertions on a RestAssured's ValidateableResponse class (i.e., xxxyyzz.then().body(matchers)). Here, I have many JSON key-value pairs in this response and I can use .then().body("path",hasKey(operator)) method for each JSON key, however, this is very tiresome. Is there any other,more efficient, way to validate multiple JSON keys?

best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to validate a list/array of some entities, you can do the following:

```
   response
      .getBody()
      .jsonPath()
      .getList("data.owner_type")
      .forEach(ownerType -> hasKey("public"));
```